# Android: How to send a HTML EMAIL with URL image

Tags: android, email

I want to send a html content email with URL image inside the application.
The HTML content is like that

i try the following code but not working

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TITLE");
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    String sharingContent="<html><body><img src='http://www.XXXX.asdasd.png?_t=1341552822'><p><bold>HAHAHHAHAHAA</bold></p></body></html>";
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(more_cover_image_thumbnail)); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(sharingContent));
```

Comment: you have asked 20 Questions accept some of which you get correct answer

Answer (score 0):

your answer:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(sharingContent));
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```